# SQLAlchemy- Execute Stored Procedure and Populate Class

Tags: python, sql, stored-procedures, orm, sqlalchemy

Is there any way to execute a stored procedure and get back a class?

I have tried:

```
session.query(MyClass).from_statement(...)
```

Where myclass is defined as:

```
MyClass(Base):
     id = Column(Integer)
     name = Column(String)
    ...
```

I know that I should put:

```
__tablename__ ‘sometable’
```

But there is no table as all the rows are the result of a stored procedure call. Do you know any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michael Bayer REPO OWNER

SQLAlchemy does not have support for OUT parameters on any backend except Oracle at this time. In order to use OUT parameters now, you need to use the DBAPI function callproc(), see http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.callproc.

your function should look like this:

```
def execproc(procname, engine, queryParams=[]):
    connection = engine.raw_connection()
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.callproc(procname, queryParams)
        rows = list(cursor.fetchall())
        cursor.close()
        connection.commit()
        return rows
    finally:
        connection.close()
```